# Moving Player Up by holding left mouse button /space Microsoft VIsual Studio (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm not so good with Visual Studio.

I'm making a simple game and my `gameobject` (player) should move up when `Space` or `Left Mouse Button` is pressed.

Here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PixelMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 PressVelocity;
    public float maxSpeed = 5f;
    public float fowardSpeed = 1f;

    bool didPress = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    //Do Graphic & Input updates
    void update() {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            didPress = true;
        }
    }

    //Do physics engine updates here
    void FixedUpdate () {
        velocity.x = fowardSpeed;
        if (didPress == true){
            didPress = false;
            velocity += PressVelocity;
        }

        velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity, maxSpeed);
        transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

So, it should move like contrary to gravity. And when it stops holding, it continues to fall. I already have gravity I just need that "Up movement"

Comment: What behavior are you seeing? Have you debugged to see what code is actually being called, and what values are present at different stages of your expected program flow? 

Without looking to see if your code would even do what it says, your `update` method is misnamed. It should be `Update` - note the camel casing.

Comment: Did you try increasing the forward speed?

Comment: I litteraly need something like flappy bird but now with jumping, but with flying (holding space - moving up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Do Graphic & Input updates
void update() {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        didPress = true;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is because `update()` should be `Update()`

Try:

```
//Do Graphic & Input updates
void Update() {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        didPress = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick fix:  You're calling Input.GetKeyDown() and Input.GetMouseButtonDown() which only return true on the first frame that the button is pressed.

If you want a repeating event (I.E., the mouse button or space is *held* down), use Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) and Input.GetMouseButton(0).

Comment: I tried this and i have problem with float.. when i hold space it slow my background movement (backgorund moves slower)
I literlly need something like maybe flappy bird but not with jumping, but with flying (holding space moving up)

Comment: So I fixed my slow background problem `velocity += PressVelocity * Time.deltaTime;`

But stil it's only jumping not flying